# Cannot store memcache key

Tags: php

I need `memcache` for store specific configuration keys. I've integrate `memcache` inside my `Settings` class, this class is instatiated each time that a request is performed. Infact, in my own framework, all requests are shunt from `index.php`. So:

```
index.php -> autoloader (new Settings, new Model, new Controller, etc...) -> logic
```

the `Settings` class is like this:

```
include 'config.php'; //contains the `$config` array

class Settings
{
    private $_config = array();
    private static $_memcache = null;

    function __construct()
    {
       self::$_memcache = new Memcache();
       self::$_memcache->connect('localhost', 11211); //take in the php doc example

      $this->_config = $config;

      foreach($config as $item => $value)
      {
         self::$_memcache->add($item, $value);
      }
   }

   public static function set($name, $value)
   {
      self::$_memcache->set($name, $value);
   }

   public static function get($name)
   {
      return self::$_memcache->get($name);
   }
}
```

How you can see I use the `method` add, in the doc I've read that return false when a key is already setted. The value to set in memcache are taken from my `$config` array that is included by `config.php` file.

I also have two method `set` that should set a specific key, and `get` that should return a key.

The problem's that each time that this script is executed I get `true` when I `var_dump(self::$_memcache->add($item, $value));`.

I use `self` for use static method of settings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the `$config` array being passed to your `Settings` constructor?

Comment: @MarkBaker edited, missing add them in the example